# Musical performances for early 70s super robot anime

Tags: music

I was always blown away by the music of some of these tv shows, like Getter Robo G, Danguard Ace, Gaiking, etc.

It seems to be mostly orchestral music, with maybe some early analog electronic effects and electric guitar and modern drums for some of it.

Who wrote most of this music? Are there recordings of the performances, video of the orchestra or any CDs of just the music available?

I’ve found one name that stands out, Shunsuke Kikuchi. I’m looking into what I can find (so far some music for the Grandizer series).

My main interest is to see a recording of an actual performance, I’d like to see what instruments are used, how the conductor drives them all, what combination of modern and traditional instruments are used, etc.

Comment: I read a particular article with details and history of the early days of music from anime and has the references of his research that also links to more details on music and anime in general in other locations - https://www.mdpi.com/2076-0752/7/4/59

Comment: While this might be an interesting topic overall, I'm afraid there are too many questions asked here, and some are only tangentially related to each other.